# Multiple conditional assignments in C#?

Tags: c#

Okay, if I have a string that I want to be equal to something based on multiple conditions, what's the best way to implement that?

Psuedocode

```
int temp = (either 1, 2, or 3)
string test = (if temp = 1, then "yes") (if temp = 2, then "no") (if temp = 3, then "maybe")
```

Is there some concise way to do this? What would you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a switch statement as mentioned in other answers but a dictionary can also be used:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "yes");
dictionary.Add(2, "no");
dictionary.Add(3, "maybe");

var test = dictionairy[value];
```

This method is way more flexible than a switch statement and ever more readable than nested tenary operator statements.

Comment: Although I ended up using a switch in my method, I chose this answer because I really love this solution, and I did not know about this. I will be using it in all future implementations of a case like this.

Answer (score 11):

Use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
switch(temp)
{
    case 1:
        return "yes";
    case 2:
        return "no";
    case default:
        return "maybe";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string test = GetValue(temp);

public string GetValue(int temp)
{
  switch(temp)
  {
    case 1:
      return "yes";

    case 2:
      return "no";

    case 3:
      return "maybe";

    default:
      throw new ArgumentException("An unrecognized temp value was encountered", "temp");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that the approach of throwing the exception. If taken, must go better with an  InvalidEnumArgumentException, it adds more context information, don't you think?

Comment: @RandolfR-F Since the argument that was provided is an integer I would stick with the ArgumentException.  If the function was accepting an enumeration and switching on that then an InvalidEnumArgumentException would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `switch` statement

```
string temp = string.Empty;
switch(value)
{
    case 1:
        temp = "yes";
        break;
    case 2:
        temp = "no";
        break;
    case 3:
        temp = "maybe";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is:

```
String choices[] = {"yes","no","maybe"};
string test = choices[temp-1];
```

There are many different ways of actually implementing it.  Depending on what your condition variable is, you might like to implement it as some sort of key-value list. SEE Zeebonk's answer for an example.

Comment: How efficient is this in real time?? I mean compared to switch if the need is exactly what the OP asked.

Comment: Adding options.  OP gave a highly useless example, so we don't know what he's really trying to do.  Obviously creating an array for a single decision is not the way to go.  But some static structure in the class could very well be the way to do it.

Comment: @RatanSharma If the array was static and readonly it would have approximately no cost, and the cost of each test (one array access) would be about the same as a switch, if not better.

Comment: @Servy I fear static for some reason..But that makes sense to me.

Comment: @RatanSharma In this case what we really want is for it to be constant, but since there is no way to make a compile time constant string array with these values, static + readonly is the best you can do.  As long as you don't do something silly like mutate the array (and for that reason I would have it as private static readonly) it will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise answer is the nested ternary operator

```
string test = (temp == 1 ? "yes" : (temp == 2 ? "no" : (temp == 3 ? "maybe" : "")));
```

if temp values are only 1,2,3 then

```
string test = (temp == 1 ? "yes" : (temp == 2 ? "no" : "maybe"));
```

of course this is the concise answer as asked, and this doesn't means that it is the best.
If you could not exclude that, in future you will need more values to test, then it is better to use a dictionary approach as explained in the @zeebonk answer.

Comment: Which would you like to prefer, Multiple ternary operator or switch statement in this scenario?

Comment: @LolCoder, well, the OP asked for a concise solution, so the ternary operator could be the answer. However, if you anticipate that you will have other values to test in the future, then the ternary operator becomes very unreadable. In that case I prefer the switch statement or, better, the Dictionary approach.

Comment: +1 for Dictionary approach....If you would explain those stuff in your  answer, I think it'll be very helpful for future reader.....

Answer (score 1):

the obvious answer would be switch case

but just another flavor:

```
int temp = x; //either 1,2 or 3

string test = (temp == 1 ? "yes" : temp == 2 ? "no" : "maybe");
```

Answer (score 1):

This switch is closer to your pseudocode and is exact C# code:

```
int temp = /* 1, 2, or 3 */;
string test;
switch(temp)
{
    case 1:
        test = "yes";
        break;
    case 2:
        test = "no";
        break;
    case 3:
        test = "maybe";
        break;
    default:
        test = /* whatever you want as your default, if anything */;
        break;
}
```

Your pseudocode doesn't include a default case, but it's good practice to include one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn things around:

```
class Program
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        Yes = 1, 
        No, 
        Maybe
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyEnum.Maybe.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This also is more in line that temp can be only 1, 2 or 3. If it's an int compiler won't warn you if temp gets value of 34.

You can also do this:

```
string GetText(int temp){ 
    return ((MyEnum)temp).ToString();
}
```

GetText(2) will return "No"